# Cloning activity dynamically in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-activity

I have a navigation drawer activity. I want to create multiple activities like the same dynamically as per user data.
But I guess that we cannot create entirely new activities on run-time. So, is there a way to convert my activity(navigation drawer activity) into fragment and use it? If it is possible, how can I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From You Question what I understand is that you want to create an application with an Activity having navigation drawer and different navigation items are fragments which are contained inside the activity.

You can do that easily and that is better that creating multiple activities.

read the following link and follow along same lines for doing that.

https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Fragment-Navigation-Drawer

Comment: On clicking navigation item, the entire activity along with drawer and toolbar should be cloned. And I need a way to switch between those without losing there corresponding states and data.

Comment: cloning navigation drawer and toolbar is a bad idea. You should make a container activity with Navigation drawer and toolbar and then replace fragments for different navigation items.

Comment: I am trying to avoid using Fragments. But it seems like Fragments are the only solution.

Comment: Fragments will help you in improved performance over using multiple activities.